# Can’t get cron job working on ASUSTOR NAS model AS-302T

Tags: php, cron, putty, cron-task, nas

I’ve been struggling for weeks now trying to find any info on how to successfully setup a cron on my Asustor NAS, and would really appreciate any help.
Here is what I have done via my favourite SSH program putty. I added my cron in the following file:

```
/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
```

The cron line added to the above file should run at 21:15 each night and looks as follows:

```
15 21 * * * * /volume1/Web/test/cron.php
```

After adding the above line I restarted the cron daemon (I think) with the following command:

```
/etc/init.d/S41crond restart
```

I’m not sure what I’m doing wrong, but it seems I just cannot get this cron to work.
Also if anyone can give me a good site that can help me regarding my Asustor NAS in general it would be much appreciated. I want to change a lot of settings like my database session duration, cahce and so on and I can’t find any real helpful info online. Unfortunately Asustor’s online help is really not of much help to me.

**BELOW IS ONLY ADDITIONAL INFO ON CRON.PHP FILE**
The cron.php file is really a simple file that I’m currently just using to see if I can get the cron working, here is the code inside the cron.php file:

```
<?php
$dateFile = date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').'.txt';
fopen($dateFile, "w");
?>
```

The above code works 100% when executed manually via browser.

Also works when following commands are excuted via Putty:

```
cd /volume1/Web/test/
php cron.php
```

Comment: What command do you use for executing manually?

Comment: @ErkiA meant to be via browser not command line. I edited question to reflect that.

Comment: You can add `#!/usr/bin/php` before `<?php` in head of your script, or the answer @ErkiA has given.

Comment: May be interesting for you to go through the common causes in [Debugging crontab](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info): are you mentioning the binary? is cron running? did  you try with something simple like `* * * * * echo "hello" >> /tmp/random.file` and see if this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/volume1/Web/test/cron.php is a script, not an executable. Script can only be interpreted by its interpreter, PHP in this case. Correct crontab entry in this case would be something like this:

`15 21 * * * php /volume1/Web/test/cron.php`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it did not work quite the way I intended it to work, but did lead me in the right direction. So I suggested an edit to your answer with the alternative that did work.